# Meaning of the Fourier Transform in $L^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, fourier-transform

What is the meaning of the Fourier integral in a Hilbert space?

If I have a function (vector) $f(x)\in L^2(-L,L)$ I can expand it on an orthonormal basis:
$$
f=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ku_k,
$$
where, for instance, the basis is
$$u_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}e^{-2\pi i k x/(2L)}.$$

The coefficients $c_k$ are then given by
$$
c_k=(u_k,f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2L}}\int_{-L}^Lf(x)e^{2\pi i k x/(2L)}dx,
$$

in which I used the integral definition of the scalar product.

But now, if $k$ is in the continuum, and we extend the period of the function to infinity, we have that the function $f(x)$ is given by the inverse transform

$$
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(k)e^{-2 \pi i k x}dk,
$$

where, now, the role of the $c_k$ coefficients (i.e. the contribution of each single $f(x)$) is played by the Fourier transform

$$
g(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi i k x}dx.
$$

What is the relation between the latter integral and my Hilbert space? Do we have a continuum of vectors in the basis of the vector space?

**Edit**: I do not know if my question makes sense. I am trying to understand the meaning of the Fourier transform in Hilbert spaces.

But, for instance, I read that the definition of a complete basis $\{e_i\}$ in an infinite dimensional space Hilbert space $H$ (the extension of the finite dimension definition) is given using a discrete sum.
$$
\forall x\in H \text{ we have that }||x_n-x||\rightarrow 0,
$$
where $x_n$ is the Fourier series of $x$ with respect to $\{e_i\}$.

Also
$$
x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i e_i, \;\;\; a_i=(e_i,x).
$$

What kind of meaning could have something in the continuum? Are we dealing with $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Moreover, $e^{-2\pi i k x}$, with $k$ in the continuum, is not even orthonormal.

Comment: L2 is infinite dimensional, so yes we have a continuum of vectors in the basis. It can be proven that the fourier transform maps functions from L2 to itself, so the inversion formula gives you an L2 function

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I do not understand the first sentence. The basis of $L^2$ given by $u_k$ (where $k=0,\pm1,\dots$) is a discrete set of vectors, still $L^2$, as you said, is infinite dimensional.